# Access internal load balancer DNS from peered VPC on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, load-balancing, vpc

I have a GCP internal load balancer running on private VPC subnet  `subnet-a` of a project `project-a` . I have a dns associated to this internal load balancer and it points to a private IP adress of `subnet-a`.

I want to access that DNS from another project `project-b`. I created a VPC subnet `subnet-b` on that project and I peered it to `subnet-a`. That works fine, I can ping internal addresses from `subnet-a` without issues.

But, I can't figure out how to access the internal DNS from `subnet-a` internal load balancer. Is there a way that will make me reach that internal DNS from a browser ?

Comment: Did you perform VPC peering? And is your browser is connected privately to your VPC (A or B), with an interconnect or a VPN?

Comment: Yes I performed VPC peering. Would you mind ot share any doc that explains how I can connect my browser to a VPC ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is running your browser? In a VM running in one of your VPC? Or on your workstation?

Comment: It is running on my workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have deployed an private project on GCP, only accessible from this project (VPC A). You have created a project B, with a VPC B and peered it with the project A. You can access from the project B, to the project A thanks to the private link (the peering)

Now, from your browser, running on your workstation, you need to set up the same thing: A private link from your workstation to the project A. For that, you need to create a VPN between your workstation (or your network) to the project A VPC. If you are in a company and you need a strong bandwidth, you can also set up a partner interconnect or a dedicated interconnect.

In an cases, you can't directly access from the PUBLIC internet, to your PRIVATE deployment without doing something; it's the principle, keeping private the private things. You can access them only if you open a door: A VPN/interconnect connexion, a bastion, an external load balancer, a proxy,...

Comment: Thank you this made it more clear in my head ! I'm gonna go with the cloud VPN solution.